# About Asymptotic behavior of the Bessel function of the fist kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, bessel-functions

[The question is stated as shown in the picture attached. I want to know how to prove the final expression to the combination of two Bessel functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiHgV.jpg)

Comment: I believe you would first need to obtain the asymptotics of $J_{\nu  + \kappa } (\nu \operatorname{sech}\alpha )$ as $\nu\to+\infty$ with $\alpha>0$ and bounded $\kappa$. This can be achieved by an application of the method of steepest descents to the integral representation $$J_{\nu  + \kappa } (\nu \operatorname{sech}\alpha ) =
\frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\int_{\infty  - \pi i}^{\infty  + \pi i} {e^{ - \nu (t -  \operatorname{sech}\alpha \sinh t)} e^{ - \kappa t} dt} .$$ The asymptotics at leading oder may be the same as that for the special case $\kappa=0$, but this has to be shown.

Comment: Hi, Gary, thank you for your hint, but would you please kindly should me how to obtain that since I am not that familiar with such technic. Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at R. Wong's Asymptotic Approximations of Integrals. The medhod is described in Chapter II, Section 4. The example of the Hankel and Bessel functions (for the case $\kappa=0$) is worked out in details in Example 8 starting on page 94.

Comment: Great, thank you very much, Gary!